# Framework for data transmission between Android/ IOS app and gateway (backend server)

Tags: java, php, android, ios, encryption

I am going to work on an Android application and for that I would be needing a backend server.

How can I make a secure data communication between android app and backend server. Is there any framework available to do this task?.

As of now what I am thinking is that before sending data to server, encrypt the sending string and then once server receives the string it decrypt it, process it and send the encrypted response and then again the mobile app will decrypt the received response and process it accordingly.

I need your help on choosing the right way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To secure the communication you need to use HTTPs (ssl/tls) and an authentication mechanism.  If you are new too programming Rest services, I recommend starting with [Google AppEngine Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android)  It will allow you to run both SSL and give you OAuth authentication. And there is an android and ios API rest client.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) backend and communicate with it over HTTPS. This gives you a simple way to allow communcation between backend and any app securely.

As for framework to use, there are many out there! If you want to write it in Java, I would suggest [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/). If you want to manage it on your own, I would still suggest to use the libraries that Dropwizard uses: Jersey (REST support, implements the JAX-RS API) and Jackson (for JSON support).